# The best way to proxy a request from the Play framework to rest application server

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, playframework, apache-karaf

I have the following architecture

> [angularjs service] -> [play framework] -> [REST service; Karaf]

I would like to download a file from Karaf Application server.

Here is my code of the Karaf:

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile() {
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=newfile.zip");
    return response.build();
}
```

and then I developed a Play controller with the following method

```
public static Result direct(String file) {
        String path = null;
        try {
            path = request().getHeader("Service-End-Point");
            if (path==null) path = request().getQueryString("Service-End-Point");
            if (path==null) path = file;
            System.out.println(path);
            URL url = new URL(path);

            return ok(url.openStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Path " + path + " is not working...");
            return badRequest("server didn't answer");
        }
    }
```

on the conf/routes file

```
GET   /direct         controllers.Clients.direct()
```

on angularjs service

```
window.location.href='./direct?url='+ http://Karaf:9000/service/get
```

it is working, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: IMHO requesting a resource from karaf out of play is not the best idea. I personally would use a proxy server such as nginx. This proxy will then handle all requests and decide to which service (play or karaf) a request will be redirected to.

Comment: Hey @Roman! :) I'd agree although sometimes going through Play may be desirable - e.g., record/validate details about the user, levels of authentication, caching/CDN, etc., before getting the resource.

Comment: @bjfletcher well yes, thats something you have to take into account when planning the system architecture (keyword SOA). As for a simple case such as venergiac asked for I'd still prefer a proxy. Another approach might be CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).